# Compile just one time in Rstudio in order to get my pdf/latex style

Tags: compilation, latex, echo, rstudio

I'm doing a LaTex document into RStudio in Windows 7 with weave Rnw files using knitr. I've have some problems such as:

- Firstly, even though I wrote echo=FALSE and results="hide" the pdf shows some code, some warnings and the loading packages, I had put WARNINGS=FALSE, ERRORS=FALSE BUT it doesn't work !

-Secondly, How can I run my code in RStudio in order to compile it just one time (downloading the big database,functions and stuff) in my .rnw file and just to put what I want to see in my pdf file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, you can change the call to `library` so that it doesn't print any output:

```
library(your_package, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
```

More generally, you can suppress messages from an expression by wrapping it in a suppressMessages:

```
suppressMessages(expr)
```

I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question and I'd recommend opening it as a separate question on SO. If you're trying to reduce the amount of time it takes to build your PDF, you might want to look at [knitr chunk caching](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/).